# Use `Abstract Syntax Trees` to get all inhereted methods of the class node

Tags: python, class, abstract-syntax-tree

I am tring to get all inhereted methods from a class by python `ast` module.  In my case, I have to use a scanning tools to read the *.py file to get all classes' inhereted method lists.

Source code:

```
# test.py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class InheritedClass(QtWidgets.QDialog, QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def closeEvent(self, bool):
        pass
```

AST code:

```
import ast

file = open('test.py', 'r')
source = file.read()


class NodeVisitor(ast.NodeVisitor):

    def visit_ClassDef(self, node):
        for base in node.bases:
            print base.__dict__


node = ast.parse(source)
visitor = NodeVisitor()
visitor.visit(node)
```

Is there a way to get all the methods inhereted by the `InheritedClass`. My thinking is go through all the parents(the node.bases attribute) of the class node, and then get their methods. But I have a blocker when I want to retrieve all methods from the parent, the `bases` attributes. And I am open to other ways.

Comment: `dir(base)` should return a `list` of all attributes of `base`, both inherited and directly defined. Is that sufficient, or do you need to separate them by where they were defined (in the parent, or in one of parent's ancestors)?

Comment: dir(base) does't work, because it is a ast node. It works for dir(QtWidgets.QDialog). I have to use ast in this case.